# jQuery UI Sortable without Ajax (submit order-data using regular form)

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using jQuery UI Sortable and I would like to submit the order of items using regular form (so, instead of using Ajax, I would like to have a form with submit button - when I submit the form, it will send the order-data to server-side).

Currently I have:

```html
<form id="frmExample" method="post">
    <ul id="sortable">
        <li id="task_1" class="ui-state-default">1</li>
        <li id="task_2" class="ui-state-default">2</li>
        <li id="task_3" class="ui-state-default">3</li>
        <li id="task_4" class="ui-state-default">4</li>
    </ul>

    <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
    $sortable.sortable({
        update: function(event, ui) {
            var $data = $(this).sortable('serialize');

            // now what? :)
        }
    });

    $sortable.disableSelection();
<script>
```

Maybe this can be done using [serialize method](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize) because in the documentation it is stated that it "*serializes the sortable's item ids into a form/ajax submittable string.*" 
... but I don't know how. 
Or maybe there is a better way (without using `serialize` method)?

Please note that I would like to submit this as an array. For example, after submitting, on backend (PHP/Laravel side) it would look something like:

```
// Result of $_POST:
// array(
//     'positions' => array('task_3', 'task_2', 'task_4', 'task_1')
// )
```

Comment: You'll want to create a hidden field `<input type="hidden" name="position">`, update it's value it on update, and then it will be sent along with the form data when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a basic example that halts the submission of the form just for this example snippet. Your code would not `e.preventDefault()`.

```js
$(function() {
  var $sortable = $("#sortable").sortable({
    update: function(event, ui) {
      var $data = $(this).sortable('toArray');
      $("#position").val(JSON.stringify($data));
    }
  });
  $sortable.disableSelection();
  $("#position").val(JSON.stringify($sortable.sortable("toArray")));
  $("#frmExample").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Form Submit, position:", $("#position").val());
  });
});
```

```css
form ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 150px;
}

form ul li {
  padding: .2em;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form id="frmExample" method="post">
  <ul id="sortable">
    <li id="task_1" class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
    <li id="task_2" class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
    <li id="task_3" class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
    <li id="task_4" class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  </ul>
  <input type="hidden" name="position" id="position" />
  <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This looks great, how could I adapt this to have value 1 in 1 hidden input, value 2 in a second hidden input and value 3 in a third? I'd like to use sortable for "top 3 options" but current DB structure has 3 separate columns for 1, 2 and 3 so need to POST as separate variables. Thanks.

Comment: @Adrian you would want to have some relationship between the two in your naming schema. So either they have a relationship with the ID or the Class... whatever works best for you. When sorting is updated, then you can iterate the list items and populate the corresponding hidden input items.